# wow.js and ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I using the following code to load in AJAX content

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.outer-nav a').on('click', function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
            $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'100%' }).empty();
        } 
        $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'100%' },function() {

            $('#ajax').load('slide-fade-content.html ' + href, function() {
                if (window.location.hash == "href") {

                    }

                $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow');
                $('#showMenu, .open').fadeIn('slow');
                $('.container').css('pointer-events', 'auto');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

slide-fade-content.html looks something like this

```
<div id="load">
 <div id="first-item>
 content
 </div>
 <div id="second-item>
 content
 </div>
</div>

and my index.html has links like this <a href="#first-item">Link 1</a>
```

and then this to activate wow.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#showMenu").click(function() {
        $('#logo, #details-wrapper, #side-text').fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

But wow.js doesn't seem to be working and i'm not getting any errors. I tested the code on a plain website with no ajax and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have a space between the file you're trying to load and the href variable? that might explain why the ajax call isn't working.

```
$('#ajax').load('slide-fade-content.html ' + href, function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

#### See WOW.js [Issue #71](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/71).

The short answer is, right now WOW.js doesn't support asynchronously loaded content. It will, once we fix that issue.